# Fatal Error PatchWork/utf8 with Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, composer-php, vendor

I cloned a site on github, and i had an error with the vendor folder because it wasn't be installed with composer install or update so i've copied the vendor folder from a fresh laravel project and i don't have anymore the followed error :
`bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php. Failed to open stream: No such file or directory. The "vendor" folder does not exist.`

but when i'm going to the public folder of laravel, i've this error again:

`Fatal error: Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\hguitare\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 46`

I've tried to `dump-autoload` and `composer update` but nothing is working

I've also tried to add this line on the composer.json into required 
`"patchwork/utf8": "1.1.*"`
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing/commenting the `'Patchwork\Utf8\Utf8ServiceProvider'` or the service provider related to this in `config/app.php` and then try installing by `composer install`

Comment: I can't relate any 'Patchwok\Utf8\Utf8ServiceProvider' on my app.php

Comment: Some where Patchwork is there in configuration files, that blocks you to do a composer install, do one thing, do a file search for `Patchwork` or any related term inside all configuration files and configuration search, if something occurs remove them or comment them out.

Comment: I've found , the vendor is  here path `/path/nameproject/vendor` i've copied his content and past on the vendor in `/path/nameproject/laravel/vendor` is a little bit confuse to me but i haven't anymore the error said.

But i've this eror now `Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\hguitare\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 59`

Comment: don't search for vendor , but search for the package name or package provider class

Comment: On `projectname\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support` there is no LoaderClass, maybe it is the cause ? Or i don't know, i need to be a little bit deflowed, i don't really understand how it's work